# How create unique constraint on table based on two column value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select
      1 as TYPE_ID,
      0 as STATUS
from
     dual  --TEST_TBL
union all
Select
      1 as TYPE_ID,
      0 as STATUS
from
     dual --TEST_TBL
     union all
Select
      1 as TYPE_ID,
      1 as STATUS
from
     dual  --TEST_TBL
```

Status = 1 is Active, 0 is Inactive

Not allow two row TYPE_ID = 1 and STATUS = 1 or  TYPE_ID = 2 and STATUS = 1

Comment: What is the actual requirement? That a `TYPE_ID` will have only one status? Or that only one `TYPE_ID` can be active at any time? A UNIQUE constraint would allow any combination as long as it appeared once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique function-based index:

```
create unique index test_table_ix
on test_table (case when status = 1 then type_id end)
```

Only non-null values are included in an index, so the case expression evaluates to null for status 0 - meaning those rows aren't indexed - and the `type_id` for status 1 - so those are. That means `1,0` isn't indexed, but `1,1` is - and then has to be unique.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ufSBW9F)